# ASP.net Custom Validator message not displaying

Tags: asp.net, validation, client

I have a div which acts like a modal popup. Inside that, I need a validation for which I setup a custom validator. But the message doesn't get fired, though the alert box does.

My code:

```
                if ((oldFromTime <= newFromTime) && (oldToTime > newFromTime)) {
                 alert("Choose time ahead of the ones saved earlier.!");
                arguments.IsValid = false;

            }
            else {
                arguments.IsValid = true;

            }
```

And my custom validator

`<asp:CustomValidator id="cboToTimeMins_CustomValidator" ControlToValidate="cboToTimeMins" ClientValidationFunction="validateTime"
                                    Display="static" ErrorMessage="Selected time range falls in the range of the ones saved earlier...! Choose another." runat="server" ValidationGroup="Timetable"/>`

cboToTimeMins is my dropdown box, and I need to set the validation message based on the value selected from it.
Is there something wrong in my code?

P.S. I am in need of only CLIENT SIDE validation.

Comment: Where did you placed the validator in the html page?

Comment: I have the dropdown box first..followed by the custom validator..The function is placed at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Can you try inspecting the html using firebug or any browser debugger when the alert event occurred? The message might been hidden due to css or layout.

Comment: The console doesn't show the function I am using. Why's it so?

Comment: I'm sure the validation function you've written is there, since the alert statement in the function is triggered. My only concern is that whether the `cboToTimeMins_CustomValidator` element is not hidden or blocked by other html element.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the message now, thanks.

Comment: You might want to answer your own question, so that anyone facing the same issue will be able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. I removed the custom validator for the Dropdown and added it to a button instead. Also, I removed the alert message in the Javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my example solution

```
                    <td class="normal">Price<span class="required">*</span></td>
                    <td class="normal" colspan="6">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" CssClass="text" Enabled="true" runat="server"  MaxLength="10" Width="100px" />
                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPrice"
                                    ErrorMessage="* Please Input Your Price" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="hdrValidation"/>

                    </td>
```

And you need to validate

```
 Page.Validate("hdrValidation")
        If Not Page.IsValid Then Exit Sub
```